# $f^{-1} $ is continuously differentiable.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

Let $f(x,y)=(x^3+y^2, xy+y^4)$.

I am trying to show that $f^{-1}$ is continuously differentiable at $(1,-1)$.

**Solution:**

$$Df(x,y)=\begin{pmatrix}3x^2 & 2y \\ y & x+4y^3\end{pmatrix} $$

$$Df(-1,1)=\begin{pmatrix}3& -2\\ -1 &-3 \end{pmatrix}$$

$$\lvert Df(1,-1)\rvert=-9-(2)=-11\neq0$$

Thus, $f^{-1}$ exists and is continuously differentiable at $(-1,1)$.

---

Is this enough to prove?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems okay to me but (especially at beginner level I assume you're at) you should explicitly invoke the inverse function theorem at the very end.

Comment: Yes I am beginner student. Okay, I will do this. Thanks.

Comment: I have a question. Let a matrix be $DF(x,y,z)=\begin {pmatrix} a & b & c\\ d & e & f\\ g & h & m\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: I want to calculate $\nabla _{F(x,y,z)}= aem - bd- ceg$ right?

Comment: @Rsm1: I don't really understand the question. Are you asking about the formula for the determinant of a $3\times 3$ matrix?

Comment: Not need. Thank you so much. If you have time, please can you look at that question? We need to learn its solution properly. @tomasz http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/447355/inverse-function-theorem-question

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but more detail is probably needed if this is homework. $f:\mathbb{R}^{2}\to\mathbb{R}^{2}$ has continuous partial derivatives, hence its derivative (a linear transformation from $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ to $\mathbb{R}^{2}$) is represented in the standard basis $\{(1,0),(0,1)\}$ at each point $(x,y)$ by the partial derivatives of $f$ as you have written. At the particular point $(−1,1)$ $J[f]\neq0$ and so by the inverse function theorem there exists an open set $U$ which contains $(−1,1)$ and an open set $V$ where $f^{-1}$ is defined and takes $V$ into $U$ in a one-to-one fashion.

Comment: This explanation is so good. Thank you:)