# Inverse function theorem application

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, derivatives

[image]

[image]

I have to solve this question with this solution way. But I made some mistakes while solving. I cannot see thesemistakes. And I cannot reach the wanted result properly. Please somebody helps me. Thank you so much. I Will be happy to help me.

### -----

I added an example from my notebook. I need to solve the question 11.6.4(above picture) with this example's solution way. I tried to solve the question 11.6.4 with this solution way. But I failed.

The example's photo is folowing..

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: in 2) why do you have $4\times 4$ matrix rather than $4\times 2$?

Comment: In fact, I have just learnt this solution way. I could not solve totally knowingly. But I need to use this solution way. I have an exam tommorow. I have to learn this. Please can you solve this question below answer in detail? Thank you so much @Ilya

Comment: There I Try to find $DF(u,v,x,y)$. For the similar question on the notebook, I wrote so @Ilya

Comment: This is really the *implicit* function theorem, and in finding the solution this way, you are deriving the proof of the implicit function theorem from the inverse function theorem. As for your answer, I am having trouble understanding what you mean by "at $ux=1/2$, $vx=1/2$, $\nabla DF \neq 0$". First of all, $\nabla$ is the sign for gradient, and you should write $\Delta DF$, or better still, $|DF|$ for the determinant. Second of all, which values of $x,y,u,v$ are you plugging in here? Do they satisfy the equations at the top?

Comment: I can't really help you prep for your exam (you should have done that before). I can say about this problem: usually when you use the implicit (or inverse) function theorem, you are given a point at which the equations are satisfied. I'm not sure how you can prove such a relation as you have written in the absence of knowing such a point. Perhaps someone else here knows that.

Comment: If there exist a point, I can solve this well. But there s No point value. So I could not do. Thank you. @EricAuld

Comment: Why not try $(x,y,u,v)=(0,1,\sqrt{7},3)$?

Comment: Well, how do you find this points? @EricAuld

Comment: Really, these points provide the two equations. Is this true and valid to use these points? @EricAuld

Comment: I just hunted around until I found one. Certainly if you find that $u^2 + v^2 = 16/(x+y)$ near this point, it does not prove that this relation holds at every point in $\{(x,y,u,v) \mid \text{Both polynomials P and Q} = 0 , \, \frac{\partial(P,Q)}{\partial(u,v)}\neq 0\}$

Comment: $(\sqrt{7})^2+9=16/(0+1)$ that is, this point holds for that equation. I can use this point. @EricAuld

Comment: What is the source of this question?

Comment: William wade's introduction to analysis book question: 11.6.4 @EricAuld

Comment: I added the similar example's photo. Maybe, helps you@EricAuld thank you so much.

Comment: I have tried to post a clearer version of the question here. Perhaps we will get an answer.  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/447475/use-implicit-function-theorem-and-show-ux-y2vx-y2-frac16xy

Comment: I am grateful of you so much. You are so helpful. Thank you thank you:)) @EricAuld

Comment: Check the link, Daniel Fischer has pointed out a very easy way to find the relation. And you're welcome. It is a good problem!

Comment: Got it:) That's $F(x,y,u,v)+G(x,y,u,v)=x(u^2+y^2)-y(u^2+v^2)=16 Then, $u^2+v^2=16/(x+y) $ is proved. And also, your points $(0,1,\sqrt{7},3)=(x_0,y_0,u_0,v_0)$ is satisfied the contion. @EricAuld

Comment: Got it:) That's $F(x,y,u,v)+G(x,y,u,v)=x(u2+y2)−y(u^2+v^2)=16$Then,$u^2+v^2=16/(x+y)$ is proved.And also,your points $(0,1,\sqrt{7},3)=(x_0,y_0,u_0,v_0)$ is satisfied the condition. @EricAuld

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Jacobian is $4uv(x^2-y^2)$, so it is nonzero where $u,v\neq 0$ and $|x|\neq |y|$. To derive the desired relation, simply add the two equations, and divide by $x+y$.

Comment: I understand thank you:))